# 500 Error when trying to access my site with LDAP authentication

Tags: apache-2.4, openldap, 500-error

### SOLVED

### Well I solved this problem. I configure my apache error log to debug level, and this way I can see that the error was my DN syntax (you can see it on error lines below) Then I go to check the 000-default.conf file and I see that instead of "dc=xxx" y wrote cd=xxx". Thanks for all the help that you give.

Here's my problem.

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server with LDAP server configured and I have another server with a web application that I use for develop de web application. This server is configured to authenticate on LDAP server and it works fine, I can authenticate on LDAP.

Well my problem now is that I have to move the web app to another server, the "real" server where the app it's going to work. The apache2 configuration (000.default.conf) is the same of the development server, and when I try to aunthenticate to LDAP, it shows the user and password pop-up but when I press to accept, it shows a Internal Server Error (500).

Thanks for all possible solutions.

Editing one more time. Searching how to better configure my apache error log I finish get some lines with an error, here is the generated lines of the access try

[Thu May 14 17:09:13.571921 2015] [authz_core:debug] [pid 18085] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 172.20.20.58:2840] AH01626: authorization result of Require valid-user : denied (no authenticated user yet)

[Thu May 14 17:09:13.572018 2015] [authz_core:debug] [pid 18085] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 172.20.20.58:2840] AH01626: authorization result of : denied (no authenticated user yet)

[Thu May 14 17:09:17.093748 2015] [authz_core:debug] [pid 18085] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 172.20.20.58:2840] AH01626: authorization result of Require valid-user : denied (no authenticated user yet)

[Thu May 14 17:09:17.093805 2015] [authz_core:debug] [pid 18085] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 172.20.20.58:2840] AH01626: authorization result of : denied (no authenticated user yet)

[Thu May 14 17:09:17.093917 2015] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 18085] mod_authnz_ldap.c(501): [client 172.20.20.58:2840] AH01691: auth_ldap authenticate: using URL ldap://172.20.20.19:389/dc=gesac,dc=ldap?uid

[Thu May 14 17:09:17.094814 2015] [ldap:debug] [pid 18085] util_ldap.c(372): AH01278: LDAP: Setting referrals to On.

[Thu May 14 17:09:17.098442 2015] [authnz_ldap:info] [pid 18085] [client 172.20.20.58:2840] AH01695: auth_ldap authenticate: user rs authentication failed; URI /MyWeb/phpinfo.php [LDAP: ldap_simple_bind() failed][Invalid DN syntax]

[Thu May 14 17:09:17.424790 2015] [authz_core:debug] [pid 18086] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 172.20.20.58:2842] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted

[Thu May 14 17:09:17.424886 2015] [authz_core:debug] [pid 18086] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 172.20.20.58:2842] AH01626: authorization result of : granted

Here are the modules enabled on both server, are the same

- core_module (static)
- so_module (static)
- watchdog_module (static)
- http_module (static)
- log_config_module (static)
- logio_module (static)
- version_module (static)
- unixd_module (static)
- access_compat_module (shared)
- alias_module (shared)
- auth_basic_module (shared)
- authn_core_module (shared)
- authn_file_module (shared)
- authnz_ldap_module (shared)
- authz_core_module (shared)
- authz_groupfile_module (shared)
- authz_host_module (shared)
- authz_user_module (shared)
- autoindex_module (shared)
- cgi_module (shared)
- dir_module (shared)
- env_module (shared)
- filter_module (shared)
- ldap_module (shared)
- ldap_userdir_module (shared)
- mime_module (shared)
- mpm_prefork_module (shared)
- negotiation_module (shared)
- php5_module (shared)
- reqtimeout_module (shared)
- rewrite_module (shared)
- setenvif_module (shared)
- socache_shmcb_module (shared)
- ssl_module (shared)
- status_module (shared)

Comment: What's in your error logs?

Comment: Nothing appears, sorry for miss out this

Comment: Can you compare the apache modules running on your development server with those on the production server?

Comment: There are the same modules enabled in both servers, here are.

Comment: Sure there is nothing in your apache error_log?

Comment: I get finally this errors on error_log, edited on post. Thanks for help

Comment: Could you post the configuration for LDAP? `Invalid DN Syntax` message suggest you have some problem in configuration